# Boolean Difference not working with joined mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to perform a really simple boolean as shown below:

[image: Boolean]

However, I get this as a result:

[image: Result]

Rather than boolean-ing all of the cylinders, it only does it for one. I have no idea what's causing this. Can anyone take a look at my file and possibly help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booleans can be extremely finicky about their placement sometimes - often all you have to do is change the "cutter" object's placement a little. Unless the position must be EXTREMELY accurate (No more than 0.001 units off), this can usually serve as a solution. Case in point: I was able to achieve this result by rotating the small cylinder group 0.001 degrees on the Z-axis before applying the boolean:

[image: PickyBoolean]

Comment: This was it. As well as tweaking the rotation, I was also able to get it to work by modifying the overlap threshold a very tiny bit. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

**Too close vertexes is not friendly for boolean to work properly:(**

The key is to avoid too close vertexes. There are two methods below.

1. Use individual origins to shrink all cylinders a little bit, you'll get what you need.
2. You can also rearrange the topology of the base part, more or less subdivision.

[image]

[image]

[image]